# Chrome extension to parse google search results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a little extension that checks the google search results for wikipedia articles, and adds a little extra link afterwards. But am having a little trouble parsing the search results. Its very simple at present.

Manifest:

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Test Test",
"icons":{
    "128":"icon_128.png"
    },
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://www.google.com/*",
    "https://www.google.com/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*", "https://www.google.com/*"],
      "css": ["style.css"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.min.js", "injector.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
],
"manifest_version": 2
}
```

And injector:

```
function findWikipediaLinks(){
console.log("here I am!");
console.log($('a'));
//.css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
}

findWikipediaLinks();
```

The problem seems to be that the code here runs before the actual search results are shown. (the results logged are the a's in the google header bar. Is there a way to time this propperly?

Comment: Have you tried running your code when the DOM is ready? In jquery you can do it this way: `$(function() {/*code here*/});`

Comment: @MMM Yeah - still gives the same result :(

Comment: Just a suggestion, with Google Instant results the content is loaded using AJAX. You probably need to intercept that event. How about a loop that runs every couple seconds?

Comment: Please provide the URL(s) you are testing with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is loading results via AJAX so you need to use an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) for `DOMNodeInserted` events.

```
function filterResultInserts(event) {
  console.log(event);
}

target.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', filterResultInserts);
```

Within `filterResultInserts` you will have to look for classes or ids that match results and modify them.

Comment: @Tim trying to implement something similar, got the final code that worked for you?

Comment: @PremN. It was a while ago, but I remember being able to use js/jquery to parse the results after each inserted dom node, like above. Sadly though, I don't still have the code. Sorry.