# Howsend parameter to google through android application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have one application containing some text fields and radio button.now I want to take these values of text views and radio buttons and send it to Google for searching when i click on Search button, and after searching  i want to also receive data from Google.Currently am able to switch to google using Intent,but I am not able to send values of text fields to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're launching your `Intent` using a url like

```
http://www.google.com
```

Instead, you can use

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=myParam
```

where myParam is the thing you're searching for.

You can get this text from an `EditText` like this

```
mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
String myParam = mEdit.getText().toString();
```

Then you can set your url in the `Intent` you launch to be

```
String intentURL = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + myParam;
```

To search for multiple parameters, separate them using '+'s. E.g.

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=myParam+myParam2
```

The following question offers a way to handle the returned results: [Chrome extension to parse google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180689/chrome-extension-to-parse-google-search-results)