# Chrome extension to parse Google results doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been experimenting with the Chrome extensions mechanism, and been trying to write an extension that would manipulate Google results (add comments, screenshots, favicons, etc.)

So far I've managed to write a code that uses a RegEx to add imgs to a link, and it works ok.

The problem is that it doesn't work on Google results.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180689/chrome-extension-to-parse-google-search-results) that it happens because the page hasn't fully loaded; so I added a 'DOMContentLoaded' listener but it didn't help.

Here's my code (content script):

```
function parse_google()  {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(
        new RegExp("<a href=\"(.*)\"(.*)</a>", "g"),
        "<img src=\"http://<path-to-img.gif>\" /><a href=\"$1\"$2</a>"
    );
alert("boooya!");
};
alert("content script: before");
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', parse_google(), false);    
alert("content script: end");
```

I get all "alerts", but it doesn't work for google. Why?

Comment: the regex is badly shown, but it works. all it does is add a <img> tag wherever there's a <a href> tag.

Comment: Not completely clear on what the question is since the link you provided would seem to solve your issue. You'll get better answers if you ask a more specific question than the very broad "can you advise".

Comment: Mike, thanks for the answer.
The problem is that I've follow the method demonstrated there, and it hadn't solved the problem. I still can't have my regex affect the google results.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you tried to listen to DOMNodeInserted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"DOMContentLoaded" refers to the static HTML of the page, but Google's search results are fetched using AJAX, thus are not there yet when the "DOMContentLoaded" event is triggered.

You could use a **[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** instead, to observe "childList" DOM mutations on a root node and its descendants.
(If you choose this approach the **[mutation-summary library](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/)** might come in handy.)

After a (really shallow) search, I found out that (at least for me) Google places its results in a `div` with **id** `search`. Below is the code of a sample extension that does the following:

1. Registers a MutationObserver to detect the insertion od `div#search` into the DOM.
2. Registers a MutationObserver to detect "childList" changes in `div#search` and its descendants.
3. Whenever a `<a>` node is added, a function traverses the relevant nodes and modifies the links. (The script ignored `<script>` elements for obvious reasons.

This sample extension just encloses the link's text in `~~`, but you can easily change it to do whatever you need.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            ...
            "*://www.google.gr/*",
            "*://www.google.com/*"
        ],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }],

}
```

**content.js:**

```
console.log("Injected...");

/* MutationObserver configuration data: Listen for "childList"
 * mutations in the specified element and its descendants */
var config = {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};
var regex = /<a.*?>[^<]*<\/a>/;

/* Traverse 'rootNode' and its descendants and modify '<a>' tags */
function modifyLinks(rootNode) {
    var nodes = [rootNode];
    while (nodes.length > 0) {
        var node = nodes.shift();
        if (node.tagName == "A") {
            /* Modify the '<a>' element */
            node.innerHTML = "~~" + node.innerHTML + "~~";
        } else {
            /* If the current node has children, queue them for further
             * processing, ignoring any '<script>' tags. */
            [].slice.call(node.children).forEach(function(childNode) {
                if (childNode.tagName != "SCRIPT") {
                    nodes.push(childNode);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

/* Observer1: Looks for 'div.search' */
var observer1 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    /* For each MutationRecord in 'mutations'... */
    mutations.some(function(mutation) {
        /* ...if nodes have beed added... */
        if (mutation.addedNodes && (mutation.addedNodes.length > 0)) {
            /* ...look for 'div#search' */
            var node = mutation.target.querySelector("div#search");
            if (node) {
                /* 'div#search' found; stop observer 1 and start observer 2 */
                observer1.disconnect();
                observer2.observe(node, config);

                if (regex.test(node.innerHTML)) {
                    /* Modify any '<a>' elements already in the current node */
                    modifyLinks(node);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});

/* Observer2: Listens for '<a>' elements insertion */
var observer2 = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes) {
            [].slice.call(mutation.addedNodes).forEach(function(node) {
                /* If 'node' or any of its desctants are '<a>'... */
                if (regex.test(node.outerHTML)) {
                    /* ...do something with them */
                    modifyLinks(node);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

/* Start observing 'body' for 'div#search' */
observer1.observe(document.body, config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an extension that manipulates Google search results. It seems the issue is that the results are almost always fetched via AJAX. I used [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to periodically check for changes in the results. There are two types of Google Search pages (which I have encountered thus far): Standard and Google Instant. For standard pages, you need to observe the body element (you can use selector "#gsr"), but for Google Instant, you can just look for the containing DIV ("#search"). You will want to observe childList and subtree mutations.

(Edited per @ExpertSystem's comments)

Comment: `setInterval` is overkill for this task. Use a MutationObserver instead.

Comment: The problem with MutationObserver is that in some instances the result elements and their parents are not yet present. I guess it can still be done, but it will take more complicated coding.

Comment: The body is always present, so there you go for an ancestor :) (99.9% percent of the time there is some parent container deeper in the hierarchy that is present from the beginning.

Comment: True - now only to figure out why the observer isn't firing on Google.com

Comment: Who says it isn't firing ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem: I got it to work and I updated my extension and my answer accordingly. Thanks!